# How to Search engine optimization (SEO) to get sub links?

Tags: search, seo, search-engine, keyword, meta-tags

What I'm trying to do is Search engine optimization (SEO) a particular web site. I would like to get sub links as shown below.

[image]

Just few guidelines would be enough. Given that I have gone through basic Search engine optimization (SEO) stuff and unable to find how to get this done.

**What are procedure should I take to achieve this?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks

Comment: if you can post this as an answer with a small explanation, I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buzz word you are looking for is Sitelinks ([link to the explaination](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en)), well google does not tell how you can get these site links, but taking a shot in dark at the algorithm it seems that you need to build your website with a very good navigation system, meaning the navigation should be in proper `<nav> <ul> <li>` tags, have proper title. You should take care of the sitemap both (sitemap.xml and html sitemap), micro-formats, structured data etc.

One more thing to note is that Google shows sitelinks only for search results that rank at the top, so it is most important to have your website rank at top position for some keyword.

I reckon you follow all the SEO guidelines by Google and you should have the sitelinks, it is not really difficult to get.